# Date is converted to default after saving to Kafka

Tags: date, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I have saved the data in Avro (Generic Record) format into Kafka and then retrieved it. The data consists of 2 String type fields and Date type. When I save to Kafka I have to convert Date to time. However, when I get the date back it is set to some default value. How it can be fixed?

The date before writing to Kafka: `2019-03-19`
Datetime saved to Kafka: `1552953600000`

Datetime retrieved from Kafka: `1824561152`
The date converted from datetime: `1969-12-10`

Here is the code for writing into Kafka:

```
val avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(parseAvroSchemaFromFile("/avro-offset-schema.json"))
avroRecord.put("stringValue", tableNameValue)
avroRecord.put("stringValue2", codeValue)
avroRecord.put("date", state)

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, GenericRecord](kafkaParams)
val data = new ProducerRecord[String, GenericRecord](kafkaTopic, avroRecord)
producer.send(data)
```

The code for reading the data from Kafka:

```
val dataRDD = KafkaUtils.createRDD(
  sparkSession.sparkContext,
  sparkAppConfig.kafkaParams.asJava,
  offsetRanges,
  LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
)

val genericRecordsValues = dataRDD.map(record => record.value().asInstanceOf[GenericRecord])

val genericRecordsFields = genericRecordsValues.map(
  record =>
    (
      record.get("TableName").toString,
      record.get("Code").toString,
      new Date(record.get(dayColumnName).asInstanceOf[Long])))

genericRecordsFields.first()
```

Comment: Look at the values immediately from `genericRecordsValues`. I think `asInstanceOf[GenericRecord` is the issue because you're not actually parsing the bytes

Comment: I am not sure that it is connected with conversion to GenericRecord. As before I used the same pipeline only instead of Date there was Timestamp, there were no problems with that. However, there I used Long type while here I had to use Int for Dates

Comment: I guess my point is that `asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]` contains no reference to a schema, so it's not clear what Kafka deserializers you've configured to know how/if that Avro data should be parsed as anything but the defaults (nulls and zeros), for example `new Date(0)` is what you're getting

Comment: Actually, it does. I've just omitted the line with a schema for clarity. Also, I write the data with a schema, so when I retrieve GenericRecord it has a proper Avro schema